# GPU Compute on Android?

Tags: android, cuda, gpu

How do I program the existing GPU architectures on Android. And is there a possibility that in the near future Android will be fully supported by CUDA perhaps maybe through an Android-based dev kit like Jetson TK1.
I've read about Renderscript but I think it is tailored more for image processing. But I'm planning on doing simulations instead. So is there a way I can get these simulations on the android platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much opportunities to develop CUDA apps for Android except for developing for devices that employ CUDA enabled GPU such as Tegra K1, example of such device is NVIDIA SHIELD. Then you can grab [Tegra Android Development Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) and start your development right away.